# KeyDown not passing all pressed keys when umlaut key is pressed

Tags: c#, winforms, keydown

To start off: I use a german keyboard, thus I have keys for the german umlauts.

#### Description

While writing up a listener for the `KeyDown` event, I noticed that some keys can't be captured at the same time, so for example if I press `Ü, O, I, U` and then a  `P`, the `P` get's ignored. However if I don't press the `Ü` i get the full `P, O, I, U`. This also happens with combinations like `Ä, A, S, D, F` which get's truncated to `Ä, A, S`, although without the `Ä` it's `A, S, D, F`.

#### Minimal example

I suppose it's easier to understand if you saw it, so here's a minimal example of what I'm doing. Note that you need to create a form `Form1` as pasting all the skeleton outside of the form would distract from the example.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<Keys> pressedKeys;
    private Label label;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        pressedKeys = new List<Keys>();

        label = new Label();
        label.Location = new Point(100, 100);

        Controls.Add(label);

        KeyUp += Form1_KeyUp;
        KeyDown += Form1_KeyDown;
    }

    private void UpdateLabelText()
    {
        label.Text = string.Join(", ", pressedKeys.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var key = e.KeyData;

        if (!pressedKeys.Contains(key))
        {
            pressedKeys.Add(key);
            UpdateLabelText();
        }
    }

    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        pressedKeys.Remove(e.KeyData);
        UpdateLabelText();
    }
}
```

#### Actual question

Is there a way to capture all keyboard events in Windows Forms, disregarding of what key was pressed?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_%28key%29

Comment: This is not a problem with your code, it's a problem with your keyboard. Usually the usb keyboards don't have that problem, but if it's a cheap one then it can happen, replace your keyboard with a good one.

Comment: Thanks, it's indeed the rollover of my keyboard, I didn't know about that. I guess I searched to specifically for C# to find this article. @Gusman: it's actually a laptop keyboard, so replacing it would be quite a hassle.